Can the HTML dialog element be opened as modal without JavaSctipt method showModal()?
Seems odd that you can set the "open" attribute on a dialog element with HTML, equivalent of JavaScript method show(), but there is no attribute equivalent to the JavaScript method showModal().
Attribute "open" on HTML dialog element, button X can be clicked:


<button>X</button>
<dialog open>
  Example
</dialog>



JavaScript method show() on HTML dialog element, behaves like setting the attribute "open" (above script), button X can be clicked:


document.getElementById('my-dialog').show();
<button>X</button>
<dialog id="my-dialog" open>
  Example
</dialog>



JavaScript method showModal() on HTML dialog element, button X cannot be clicked as expected due to modality:


document.getElementById('my-dialog').showModal();
<button>X</button>
<dialog id="my-dialog">
  Example
</dialog>



What kind of attribute I would expect as equivalent of showModal() (above script) but in HTML without the need for JavaScript. Button X can be clicked since no dialog has been opened as modal, the attribute "open-modal" does not exist.


<button>X</button>
<dialog open-modal>
  Example
</dialog>



Attribute "open-modal" is an example name for demonstration of the attribute that does not seem to exist, but I would expect to exist.
Do I miss something or opening (as shown above) a dialog element can be done both via HTML and JavaScript, but opening it as modal dialog can only be done via JavaScript?

what the css framework did you use?

@TaurusSilver none, pure CSS.

I think is imposible just pure css, file you need some javascript to fire the event handler.

Your question needs a bit of clarification. I can understand that to you it seems obvious what you're asking, but we have no context at all. What does: "Open a dialog with HTML", mean? Why not add some code to your question that shows us what you're talking about, or perhaps, if that's too much, a link to documentation or an example? Please don't add to your question in a comment.

@KIKOSoftware I just added relevant scripts for demonstration and refined my wording. Thanks for mentioning., hopefully its less blurry now.

Yes, it's quite a bit clearer now. Please read this: dialog open attribute. I think this could have been even more explicit: The open attribute should only be used when designing dialogs, it is not meant to be use in production. The idea here is that it is a handy way to see what you're doing when you're creating the HTML of the dialog. After that you remove the open attribute and show it through the JS methods of the dialog element.

Here are the HTML Living Standard specs.

@KIKOSoftware I see, that is more reasonable now, but even if it is meant for testing as you mentioned, weird that the showModal cannot be tested like that since it is the one with more strict rules and visuals like the backdrop.

Yes, I agree it is a bit weird, but I think that the open attribute was an afterthought. Let me see if I can find anything about that. Your point is discussed here and you can follow that thread through the years. I haven't found anything definitive about why they created the dialog element this way, but as you can see that was roughtly a decade ago.
